# sql query to select almost similar rows based upon of the column value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date, duplicate-data

There are scenarios in which there are 2 entries for same number (91132310000) and different billing system (A and B) and having same start date (07-JUL-03) but different end date So I need to select the max start date row.

Below table is output of removing the duplicate rows

```
BILLING ACCOUNT     NUM         START_DATE  END_DATE    STATUS  
A       AA54340152  91132310000 07-JUL-03       W   
B       AA54340152  91132310000 07-JUL-03   31-DEC-99   W   
B       AA54340152  91132310001 07-JUL-03   31-DEC-99   W
B       AA54340152  91132310002 07-JUL-03   31-DEC-99   W
```

So I am using this below query.. but it gives me one entry which have A and B billing system for NUM '91132310000' so i want entry of only A billing system. Similarly there is one more condition that if billing system for same NUM is B and C then select B billing system row. These are the two condition which I am not able to script down in sql.

```
SELECT * FROM number_data A WHERE START_DATE = (SELECT MAX(START_DATE ) FROM number_data B WHERE A.NUM=B.NUM'
```

Snippet from the output:

```
BILLING ACCOUNT     NUM         START_DATE  END_DATE    STATUS  
A       AA54340152  91132310000 07-JUL-03       W   
B       AA54340152  91132310000 07-JUL-03   31-DEC-99   W
```

Comment: Is this `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Group By statement.

```
 Select Num, Max(Start_Date)
 From   number_data
 Group By Num
```

This query will return a list of all the distinct 'Num' in number_data and select the max start_date

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NUM ORDER BY BILLING) AS Rk
    FROM @Billing
) d
WHERE d.Rk = 1
```

If this is for sql-server then you can use this query to get the lowest billing record for each number.